# Listbox contentcontrol with two data templates and triggers on alternationindex, xaml

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a `ListBox` with and I would like it to have 2 completely different data template styles depending on the alternation index. I've seen lots of tutorials on how to change the background colour based on the index but not changing the style on each index. Here's what I have so far.

Defined templates:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ItemLeft" >
        <Border Background="Blue" Height="10">
            <!-- Define Left Style -->

        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ItemRight">
        <Border Background="Red" Height="10">
            <!-- Define Right Style -->

        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

I've removed the data template code to make it easier to read. It's a lot more than border colours.

ListBox:

```
        <ListBox Name="StatusListBox" AlternationCount="2">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ContentControl Content="{Binding}">
                        <ContentControl.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
                                <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource ItemLeft}"/>
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type ContentPresenter}}, Path=(ListBox.AlternationIndex)}" Value="1">
                                        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource ItemRight}"/>
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </ContentControl.Style>
                    </ContentControl>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

This code doesn't set the content control properly. I'm either doing it wrong or missing a step, again. I'm new to using WPF, I've found most of it pretty intuitive but I'm lost here. I would like to try and contain this to just XAML code.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could directly set the `ItemContainerStyle` instead of styling a ContentPresenter in the ItemTemplate. The Style would have a `Trigger` instead of a `DataTrigger` for the AlternationIndex:

```
<ListBox AlternationCount="2">
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource ItemLeft}"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="1">
                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate"
                            Value="{StaticResource ItemRight}"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: I didn't even see the part about aternationindex +1